# viewpager inside pull to refresh

Tags: android

I have done a pull to refresh implementation using a relative layout(slidinglayout) sliding on top of another relative layout (mainlayout) using ontouchlistener.

So its like :
     ~mainlayout
     ~slidinglayout with ontouchlistener to enable sliding down
         ~viewpager layout
            
.......
.......

Now when i do pull to refresh on sliding layout i am able to do it on entire screen except viewpager area, since it already has its own horizontal flip . I want the touch event done on sliding layout to reach viewpager and viewpagers horizontal event should also work.

Thanks
Vaibhav

Comment: Could you intercept the motion and detect if it is a horizontal or vertical movement? If you can, maybe you can intercept the vertical moves and let the horizontal ones pass through to the viewpager... Not sure if this works, but it's just a thought...